# How to take care of handles in application?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7, window-handles

I have doubt about controlling handles of my application IpScanner(multithreded).When I run my code handles get increased every time.
For example:
If I put IP range as 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.10 and then I run my code with 10 threads it gets increased for the first time like if I have 40 handles at the start it reaches to some value lets says 56.When I again run for 10 threads then again it gets increased from 56 to certain value says 67 it goes on till I terminate my application. How to get over it Can anyone help me?

```
//Programm Scans ips and gives hostname for same
//Function IpAddrToName and function getnumberofipsinrange are used
//Two threads are used ScannerThread and ScannerChild
unit UnitHostName;

interface

uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
    Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls,WinSock,SyncObjs,TlHelp32, Buttons; //Winsock and sincobjs

type
    TIpScan = class(TForm)        //Controls are added here
    OutputField: TListView;
    lbThreadcount: TLabel;
    edtThreadCount: TEdit;
    btEnter: TButton;
    edtFromIp: TEdit;
    edtToIp: TEdit;
    lbFrom: TLabel;
    lbTo: TLabel;
    lbResult: TLabel;

        procedure btEnterClick(Sender: TObject);//Events are added here
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject); //Event formdestroy added
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject); //Event formactivate
    procedure edtFromIpKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char); //Event edttoipkeypress
    procedure edtToIpKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char); //Event edttoipkeypress
    procedure edtThreadCountKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);//Event threadcountkeypress
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);  //Event formclose
    private
  public
  End;
{Main thread ScannerThread}
type
    ScannerThread = class(TThread) //ScannerThread which is main thread inside which subthreads are generated
  Private
    LvHosts : TListview;    //Private variables of scannerthread
    Ip_From,Ip_TO : String;
    tcount : Integer;    //tcount gives threads count
    ScannerChCount: integer;
    Constructor Create(CreateSuspended:Boolean);
    protected
        procedure Execute; override;
    procedure ScanchildTerminated( Sender : TObject ); //Event for scannerchild terminated
    public
end;

{ScannerChild Thread}
type
    ScannerChild = class(TThread)  //Scannerchild class is other thread whos objects are created as input given by user
   Private
     IpTOScan : String;
     Lvhostname : TListview;

     FCriticalsection : TCriticalSection;//Critical Section variable is declared here
     Constructor Create(CreateSuspended:Boolean; IP:String);
    public
        Destructor Destroy; override;//Destructor is declared
    protected
        procedure Execute; Override;
 end;

var
  IpScan: TIpScan;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

//Function IsValidIp which checks for valid ip and returns value as true or false
Function IsValidIP(str: String):Boolean;
var
 Temp,
 DotCnt : Integer;
 TStr   : String;
Begin
// Check Ip value is in Range or not..
 Result := False;
 Dotcnt := 0;
 Try
   If Pos('.',Str) = 0 then     {check for '.'}
    Exit;

   While (Pos('.',Str) > 0) do //Checking for string after '.'
   Begin
    DotCnt := DotCnt + 1;
    TStr := Copy(Str,1,Pos('.',Str)-1);
    TStr := Trim(TStr);
    If (TStr = '') Then     //Checking if tstr is empty then result as false
    Begin
     Result := False; //Result false
     Exit;
    end;

    If (Length(TStr) > 3) or (TStr = '00') or (TStr = '000') then  //Checking if length is greater than 3 then result is false
    Begin
     Result := False;//Result is false 
     Exit;
    end;

    Temp := StrToInt(TStr);
    Delete(Str,1,Pos('.',Str));
    If (Temp > 255) or ((Temp < 0) and (DotCnt = 1))then  //checking for dotcnt and ip range
    Begin
     Result := False; //Result is false
     Exit;
    end;
    Result := True;
  end;

  If Result = True then
  Begin
  If DotCnt <> 3 then //Checking if dotcnt is not equal to 3 then result is false
  Begin
   Result := False;  //Result is false if condition is  false
   Exit;
  End;

  Str := Trim(Str);
  If (Str <> '') then
  Begin
   If (Length(Str) > 3) or (Str = '00') or (Str = '000') then
   Begin
    Result := False;  //Result is false if condition is false
    Exit;
   End;
   Temp := StrToInt(Str);
   If (Temp < 0) or (Temp > 255) then
   Begin
    Result := False;  //Result is false if condition is false
    Exit;  //Exit
   End;
  End
  else
  Begin
   Result := False;
   Exit;
  end;
 end;
 Except
  Result := False;
 End;
end;

//Function IsValidIpRange (Input : String) output : Boolean Function: which checks for valid iprange
Function IsValidIpRange( IPFrom,IPTo : String): Boolean;
Var
  CheckIp1, CheckIp2     : TStringList;     //To compare two ips
  Fr_ip1, Fr_ip2, Fr_ip3, Fr_ip4 :  Integer;       //to store ip 1
  To_ip1, To_ip2, To_ip3, To_ip4 :  Integer;       //to store ip 2
Begin
    Result:=False; //initially Result is false
    If IPFrom = IPTo Then
    Begin
      Result:=true; //ip is invalid so result:=False
      Exit;//Exit from procedure
    End;                  
    CheckIp1:=TStringList.Create; //Create TStringlist for ip1
    CheckIp2:=TStringList.Create; //Create TStringlist for ip2
    CheckIp1.Delimiter:='.';   //set delimeter
    CheckIp2.Delimiter:='.';   //set delimeter
    CheckIp1.DelimitedText:=IPFrom;  //Seperate delimited text for ip1
    CheckIp2.DelimitedText:=IPTo;    //Seperate delimited text for ip2
    Fr_ip1 := StrToInt(CheckIp1[0]);
    Fr_ip2 := StrToInt(CheckIp1[1]);
    Fr_ip3 := StrToInt(CheckIp1[2]);
    Fr_ip4 := StrToInt(CheckIp1[3]);
    To_ip1 := StrToInt(CheckIp2[0]);
    To_ip2 := StrToInt(CheckIp2[1]);
    To_ip3 := StrToInt(CheckIp2[2]);
    To_ip4 := StrToInt(CheckIp2[3]);
    If Fr_ip1 < To_ip1 Then   //If ip1's first 8 bits are Smaller that Ip2's Then Result is true
    Begin
      Result:=True;
      If Assigned(CheckIp1) Then   //Free resources
        FreeAndNil(CheckIp1);
      If Assigned(CheckIp2) Then
        FreeAndNil(CheckIp2);
      Exit;
    End;
    If Fr_ip1 = To_ip1 Then
     If Fr_ip2 < to_ip2 Then   //Checks for first 16 bits
     Begin
       Result:=True;
       If Assigned(CheckIp1) Then //Free resources
         FreeAndNil(CheckIp1);
       If Assigned(CheckIp2) Then  //Free resources
         FreeAndNil(CheckIp2);
       Exit;
     End;
    If Fr_ip1 = to_ip1 Then    //Checks for first 24 bits
     If Fr_ip2 = to_ip2 Then
      If Fr_ip3 < to_ip3 Then
      Begin
        Result:=True;
        If Assigned(CheckIp1) Then  //Free resources
          FreeAndNil(CheckIp1);
        If Assigned(CheckIp2) Then
          FreeAndNil(CheckIp2);
        Exit;
      End;
    If Fr_ip1 = to_ip1 Then      //Checks for all 32 bits
     If Fr_ip2 = to_ip2 Then
      If Fr_ip3 = to_ip3 Then
       If Fr_ip4 < to_ip4 Then
       Begin
         Result:=True;
         If Assigned(CheckIp1) Then  //Free resources
           FreeAndNil(CheckIp1);
         If Assigned(CheckIp2) Then
           FreeAndNil(CheckIp2);
         Exit;
       End;
    If Assigned(CheckIp1) Then  //Free resources
        FreeAndNil(CheckIp1);
    If Assigned(CheckIp2) Then
        FreeAndNil(CheckIp2);
End;


//Function IpAddrToName which calculates hostname of each ip address (Input : string): Output :string
function IPAddrToName(IPAddr : String): String;
var
  SockAddrIn: TSockAddrIn;
  WSAData   : TWSAdata;
  HostEnt: PHostEnt;
begin
  WSAStartup($101, WSAData);  //starting winsock session
  SockAddrIn.sin_addr.s_addr:= inet_addr(PChar(IPAddr));
  HostEnt:= gethostbyaddr(@SockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_addr, 4, AF_INET); //Getting hostname HostEnt
  If HostEnt<>nil then
    result:=StrPas(Hostent^.h_name)  //Putting in result if hostname is not empty
  Else
    result:=''; //Putting in result if hostname is empty
  WSACleanup;
end;

//This function calculates the nuber of ips presernt in the given range
function GetNumberOfIpsInRange(IpFrom,IpTo:String ;ipList : TStringList) : boolean;
var
 a, b: TInAddr;
 Strlst : TStringList;
 I1, I2, I,count: Integer;
 p : PChar;
 check : boolean;
begin
 Check := False;                     //Set check as a false
 Result:=False;                      //set result as a false if program cougth exception or IPlist is
 Count := 0;                         //Empty Then result is False
 Try
   Strlst := Tstringlist.create;            //TStringlist Created
   a.S_addr := Inet_addr(PChar(IPFrom));    //TStringlist to store ip list temporarly
   b.S_Addr := inet_addr(PChar(IPTo)) ;     // function converts the Internet host address cp from IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary data in network byte order
   I1 := ntohl (a.S_addr);                  //function converts the unsigned integer netlong from network byte order to host byte order
   I2 := ntohl (b.S_addr);
   For I:=I1 to I2 Do                //Loop to add ip list into Stringlist
   Begin
     StrLst.add(IntToStr(i));       //ip added into string list
     Check := true;                 //Set check status true if ip is valid
     Count:=Count+1;                //Increment Count
     If Count = 5000 Then           //Ckeck if Count is too large, and Show message
      MessageDlg('IP Range is too large,It will take time', mtError , [mbOK]  , 0);
     If Count = 25000 Then         //Ckeck if Count is too large, and Break
      Break;
   End;
   Count:=0;                       //initialize count
   For i1 := 0 to strlst.Count-1 Do
   Begin
      i2 := strtoint(Strlst.Strings[i1]);  //Add ip list to return ip list
      a.S_addr := ntohl(i2);              //converts the unsigned integer netlong from network byte order
      p := inet_ntoa(a);                  //converts the Internet host address cp from IPv4 numbers-and-dots notatio
      IpList.Add(p);                      //Add to IP list
      Count:=Count+1;                    //incremenet Count
      If Count=25000 Then                 //Break if Count reaches to limit
       Break;
   End;
   FreeAndNil(Strlst);          // Relesase Resources In Normal Case
   If Check Then               //Check status of Check Variable
    Result := true             //If check is True Then Reult is true
   Else
    Result := False;           //If check is False Then Reult is False
  Except
    FreeAndNil(Strlst);    // Relesase Resources In exception
  End;
end;

//Procedure for button enterclick wwhich creates main thread ScannerThread
procedure TIpScan.btEnterClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    fromIP,
    endIP    : String;  //Fromip and to ip are used for
  Count : String;   //Count is for taking thread count from edit field
    Scanner :   ScannerThread;
  ThrdCount : Integer; //thrdcount for thrds input by user
Begin
    Try
        fromIP:=Trim(edtFromIP.Text); //Taking fromip input
        endIP:=Trim(edtToIP.Text);    //Taking endip
        Count:=Trim(edtThreadCount.Text); //taking threads count
    If (fromIP = EmptyStr) or (endIP = EmptyStr)  then //checking if any field is empty
    Begin
     If fromip = emptystr then
     Begin
       ShowMessage('Provide proper input(s) for IP fields !,FromIp field is empty');
       edtFromip.setfocus; //Setting focus to edtfromip
       exit;
     end
     else
     Begin
       Showmessage('Provide proper input(s) for IP fields !,ToIp field is empty');
       edttoip.setfocus; //setting focus to edttoip
       exit;
     end;
    End;

        If (Count = EmptyStr) then  //Checking if threadcount is empty or not
    Begin
     Showmessage('Threads count cannot be empty');
      edtThreadCount.setfocus;
     Exit;
    End
        Else
     thrdCount  :=  StrToInt(Count);
    If thrdCount < 2 Then    //Thread count should not be less than 2
    Begin
     Showmessage('Thread Count Cannot be less than 2');
      edtThreadCount.setfocus;
     Exit;
    End;
    If thrdCount > 100 Then  //Thread count should not be greater than 100
    Begin
     edtThreadCount.SetFocus;
     Exit;
    End;
    If IsValidIp(FromIp) AND IsValidIp(endIP) Then //Checking for valid ip range
     Begin
      If IsValidIpRange(fromIP,endIP) Then //Checking for valid ip range
      Begin
       Scanner:=ScannerThread.create(true); //Creating scannerthread
       Scanner.IP_From:=fromIP; // Declaring variable of form as variable of scanner
           Scanner.IP_To:=endIP;
           Scanner.tCount:=thrdCount;
           Scanner.LVHosts:=OutputField;
           Scanner.Resume;
       btEnter.enabled:=false;  //Disabling button,edit fields
       edtFromIp.enabled:=false;  //Disabling fromip edit field
       edtToIp.enabled:=false;    //Disabling to ip input field
       edtThreadCount.enabled:=false;
      End
      Else
      Begin
       Showmessage('Put Valid Ip Range');
       Outputfield.items.clear;   //Clearing outputfiled
       Ipscan.edtToIp.setfocus;   //Setting focus toedttoip
       Exit;
      end;
     end
     Else
      IF IsValidIp(FromIp) = false then //checking for valid ip
      Begin
       Showmessage('Put Valid IP');
       Outputfield.items.clear;    //Clearing outputfield
       edtFromIp.setfocus;        //Setting focus 
       Exit;
      end
      Else
      Begin
       Showmessage('Put valid ip');
       Outputfield.items.clear;   //Clearing outputfield
       edtToIp.setfocus;    //Setting focus to edttoip
       Exit;
      End;
 Except
  On E: Exception do
 Begin
    ShowMessage('Exception :' + E.Message); //Exception
  End
    End;
End;

Constructor ScannerThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean );
Begin
    Inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  Freeonterminate:= true;
End;

{Main Thread }
procedure ScannerThread.Execute;
var
    I  :    integer;
    ScannerCh : array  of ScannerChild;  //array of ScannerChild
  IpList : TStringlist;
  IPs: Integer;   //ipcount is count of iplist
Begin
  ScannerchCount:=0;
  IpList:=TStringList.Create;//creating stringlist
  IF GetNumberOfIpsInRange(Ip_From, Ip_To, IpList)  Then    //Function call that returns iplist if TRUE
  Begin
    Try
      IF Assigned(LvHosts) Then        //Clearing LvHosts  field
        LvHosts.Clear;
      IPs := IpList.Count; //Ipcount is given value of iplists count
      SetLength(ScannerCh, IPs);  //Setting length of scannerch as ipcount

      I:=0;
        Repeat
          While ScannerChcount >= tcount do  //Checking if  is greater than tcount(thread input) by user
            Sleep(30);
          ScannerCh[I]:=ScannerChild.Create(True, IpList[i]);
          ScannerCh[I].FreeOnTerminate:=True;
          ScannerCh[I].OnTerminate:= ScanchildTerminated; // Event scanchildterminated occurs on termination of Scannerch thread
          ScannerCh[I].LvHostname := LvHosts;
          ScannerCh[I].Resume;
          ScannerChCount:=Scannerchcount+1;
          I:=I+1;
          Sleep(10);   //Sleep after each thread is created so that threads will enter critical section properly
       until I = IPs;

       Scannerch:=nil;
      If Assigned(IpList) Then   //Free iplist
        FreeAndNil(IpList);

    Except
      On E: Exception do
       Begin
        ShowMessage('Invalid operation :' + E.Message); //Showexception message

      If Assigned(IpList) Then          //Free iplist
         FreeAndNil(IpList);
      end;   
    End;
  End
  Else
  Begin
   Ipscan.lbResult.caption:='Invalid Ip Range';
   Ipscan.btEnter.enabled:=true;     //Enabling button,edit fields
   IpScan.edtFromIp.enabled:=true;
   IpScan.edtToIp.enabled:=true;
   IpScan.edtThreadCount.enabled:=true;
   Ipscan.edtFromIp.setfocus;
   Exit;
  End;
  Repeat                                                                      //Main Thread Waiting For Ip scan Threads to finish
   Sleep(100);
  until ScannerChCount = 0;
   Ipscan.btEnter.enabled:=true;     //Enabling button,edit fields
   IpScan.edtFromIp.enabled:=true;
   IpScan.edtToIp.enabled:=true;
   IpScan.edtThreadCount.enabled:=true;
End;

//Constructor of scannerchild is created
Constructor ScannerChild.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; IP: String);
Begin
    Inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FCriticalsection := TCriticalSection.create;  //Creating critical section
  IPToScan:=IP;
End;

//Destructor for scannerchild
Destructor ScannerChild.Destroy;
Begin
 FreeAndNil(FCriticalsection);//Free critical section
End;

//Execution procedure for scannerchild
procedure ScannerChild.Execute;
Var
 MainOutput : TListItem;//Listitem variable for adding listitems
 Hostname   : String; //Hostname is declared as string
Begin
 Try
  FCriticalsection.Acquire;    //Acquiring critical section
  MainOutput:=LvHostname.Items.Add; //Adding items to mainoutput
  MainOutput.Caption:=IPToScan;
  Hostname := IPAddrToName(IPToScan);
  If Hostname <> EmptyStr Then
  Begin
    MainOutput.SubItems.Add(IPAddrToName(IPToScan));
  End
  Else
    Mainoutput.subitems.add('No host');
  Finally
   FCriticalsection.Release; //Releasing critical section
  End;
End;

//this event get called when scannerch thread terminates
procedure Scannerthread.ScanchildTerminated( Sender : TObject );
Begin
  ScannerChCount:=ScannerchCount-1; // Decrementing scannerchcount

End;

//Procedure for formdestroy
procedure TIpScan.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
Begin
  If Assigned(OutputField) Then   //Free outputfield
    OutputField.Free;
End;

//Procedure for formactivate
procedure TIpScan.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
Begin
  edtFromIP.SetFocus;
End;

//Event edtFromkeypress for validation of edit box
procedure TIpScan.edtFromIpKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
   If not(Key IN ['0'..'9', #13,#8,'.']) then key:= #0;
   If key = chr(13) then
     btEnterClick(self); //For enter click
end;

//Event for edtToIpKeypress for validation
procedure TIpScan.edtToIpKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
   If not(Key IN ['0'..'9', #13,#8,'.']) then key:= #0;
   If key = chr(13) then
     btEnterClick(self); //For enter click
end;

//Event for edtthreadkeypress for validation
procedure TIpScan.edtThreadCountKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
   If not(Key IN ['0'..'9',#8,#13]) then key:= #0;
   If key = chr(13) then
     btEnterClick(self); //For enter click
end;
//Formclose event for teminating process
procedure TIpScan.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
   TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess, ExitCode);  //Terminating current process
end;

End.
```

unithostname.dfm

```
object IpScan: TIpScan
  Left = 245
  Top = 191
  BorderIcons = [biSystemMenu, biMinimize]
  BorderStyle = bsSingle
  Caption = 'IpScanner'
  ClientHeight = 375
  ClientWidth = 352
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poScreenCenter
  OnActivate = FormActivate
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object lbThreadcount: TLabel
    Left = 26
    Top = 74
    Width = 62
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'ThreadCount'
  end
  object lbFrom: TLabel
    Left = 24
    Top = 32
    Width = 23
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'From'
  end
  object lbTo: TLabel
    Left = 176
    Top = 32
    Width = 13
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'To'
  end
  object lbResult: TLabel
    Left = 24
    Top = 344
    Width = 4
    Height = 18
    Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -16
    Font.Name = 'Arial'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
  end
  object OutputField: TListView
    Left = 10
    Top = 104
    Width = 327
    Height = 225
    Columns = <
      item
        AutoSize = True
        Caption = 'IP Address'
      end
      item
        AutoSize = True
        Caption = 'HostName'
      end>
    ReadOnly = True
    RowSelect = True
    TabOrder = 3
    ViewStyle = vsReport
  end
  object edtThreadCount: TEdit
    Left = 113
    Top = 71
    Width = 48
    Height = 21
    MaxLength = 2
    TabOrder = 2
    OnKeyPress = edtThreadCountKeyPress
  end
  object btEnter: TButton
    Left = 241
    Top = 67
    Width = 94
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Show Hosts'
    TabOrder = 4
    OnClick = btEnterClick
  end
  object edtFromIp: TEdit
    Left = 72
    Top = 32
    Width = 97
    Height = 21
    MaxLength = 15
    TabOrder = 0
    OnKeyPress = edtFromIpKeyPress
  end
  object edtToIp: TEdit
    Left = 208
    Top = 32
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    MaxLength = 15
    TabOrder = 1
    OnKeyPress = edtToIpKeyPress
  end
end
```

If I run my code for more threads then more handles are generated everytime.How to get rid of these? Can anyone help me? thank you

Comment: i know this much when thread is created then handle is returned to the thread and when it is terminated it releases or closes handle

Comment: You should tag all of your delphi related questions with the `delphi` tag. If you wonder about the low attention (look at the viewed counter), that is the reason. Also your code will be presented with the correct highlighter.

Comment: What are you talking about? How are you counting handles?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i am getting counts of handles from task manager. i think my threads are not closing handles because of that evrytime handles are getting increased

Comment: No. Please supply a complete program. A console app. No UI. Hard coded input. Something we can run directly. As small as possible yet still showing problem.

Comment: Also please fix your tags as Sir Rufo said. I could do it but it's better for you to.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - sir this is complete program only just put ip range properly and threads count as 99

Comment: Please do it my way. It's not a complete program. There's GUI, .dfm missing, rest of unit missing. I want to paste and compile. I know what I'm doing here. Let me help you.

Comment: Now see evrythng is there. Thank you for helping me

Comment: No, not everything is there. I can't compile this. Please do it the way that I said. Read my comments again carefully.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i put .dfm file now.check it

Comment: No thanks. I'd like a console app. Sorry to be fussy, but I'm trying to teach you how to cut a problem down to its bare minimum. You still have not fixed the tags. I won't help you if you won't listen.

Comment: i put delphi 7 tag sir in start only and to put tag as delphi only i need to have certain reputation count which i am not having

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sir help?

Comment: I won't at the moment because you've not provided an MCVE to my liking. Sorry. I'd like the simplest possible program, as a console app rather than a GUI app. There's too much code here. It's a minefield.